# Can I use dynamically generated XML file in Data Driven Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to use an dynamically generated XML file with Data Driven test. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 .

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", @"|DataDirectory|\StudentData.xml", "Student", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

This `StudentData.xml` file is being generated by code and I am not deploying this file. I have written the code for generating `StudentData.xml` file in `TestInitialize()` method, also the file is being saved at current working directory.

Whenever I am going to run the test method it is throwing error:

```
The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
Error details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What I think is before creating the file, the framework is trying to access the file. So, How can I use this XML file with unit test? Also, can I use variable names in Attributes?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't gey any reply from last 17 hours. As it was important for me, so I tried to explore other possibilities.

Finally I made it to work. Below is the simple solution (I am posting this because it might help other begineers like me, in future).

I have just moved my XML file generation code to `[ClassInitialize]` method instead of `TestInitialize()` and it worked fine.

Also, below is the order that methods will be run is:

```
1.  Methods marked with the AssemblyInitializeAttribute.
2.  Methods marked with the ClassInitializeAttribute.
3.  Methods marked with the TestInitializeAttribute.
4.  Methods marked with the TestMethodAttribute
```

Check [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more

Thanks...